# Combining HTML5, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to change an editable css table extracted from codepen to something a little bit different. However, I'm having trouble simply getting the HTML5, CSS, JS and JQuery parts to work. This is the link: http://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA.

I have pasted the below codes into dreamweaver cs6. Basically the problem is that when I open up the html file I do not get the add, remove, move up and down and the CSS style on the table. It is a plain HTML table in which I can edit the names but that is all. I'm assuming I only need to open the HTML file as I've linked the CSS and JS.

Also, I'm running a local apache client and opening the html file from local host.

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang"en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csspart.css.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspart.js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <p>Through the powers of <strong>contenteditable</strong> and some simple jQuery you can easily create a custom editable table. No need for a robust JavaScript library anymore these days.</p>

  <ul>
    <li>An editable table that exports a hash array. Dynamically compiles rows from headers</li> 
    <li>Simple / powerful features such as add row, remove row, move row up/down.</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.table-editable {
  position: relative;
}
.table-editable .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-remove:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.table-up, .table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-up:hover, .table-down:hover {
  color: #00f;
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}
.table-add:hover {
  color: #0b0;
}
```

And the JS code is:

```
// JavaScript Document

var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');

$('.table-add').click(function () {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function () {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];

  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });

  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};

    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
    });

    data.push(h);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers :)

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What you want to achieve with that code ?

Comment: share what error are you getting

Comment: The main thing you are doing wrong is not explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: _'What am I doing wrong?'_ -why don't _you_ tell _us_? Describe what should happen and what is actually happening. See [ask]

Comment: Apologies, first time asking on stack overflow. I should've been more clear. I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems you have tired to copy code from codepen and make your own HTML page. If this is the case are you sure you have a copy of all the required assets.

In the html a copy of jQuery is expected in the same folder at the HTML file.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Along with another JS file which may also have an incorrect file name '.js.js'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspart.js.js"></script>
```

For the arrows to appear you will need to add bootstrap glyphicons to your project. http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: The jQuery file is in the same folder as the HTML file. I've changed the file name, and removed the extra .cs & .js. I'm still getting a plain HTML page with only editable name and value.

Comment: Do you get an errors via the console? (F12 in firefox)

Comment: Ok, I think you need to add the bootstrap CSS framework to your code. It seems to be added by default in codepen. I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: The bootstrap components are now visible. But they do not work.